# PHP limit audio file duration?

Tags: php, audio, limit, duration

I have a form where user can upload audio file (mp3), but instead of limiting the actual size of it, is it possible to limit the duration of the file in php?

Comment: The problem is that it has to be uploaded for the php to be able to open it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can process the uploaded file with [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) to determine audio length, and cut it if you wish.

You can either call it with `exec()`, or use the [PHP extension](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The *only* way to limit this *before* upload is with client-side technologies - since you would have to read the file to determine the length at the client side, in order to prevent it being uploaded if it was too long.

Obviously, this is impossible with Javascript (in this context at least) and if you really want to do it you will need a more complex approach like (for example) ActiveX or a Java applet. I believe you can also do this sort of thing with Flash. Personally I would go with the Java option, but this is simply personal preference.

If all you are concerned about is ensuring that the length of the finally stored file is limited, and are not worried about excess length files being sent to the server, then Brad's answer is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it with html form and php ..or any other server-side code. Well, actually sure you can, but if you wish to do the check before actual upload.. Only possible way to do this is to load content via flash. In flash you can nowdays load content without actually loding it to server, and there you are able to do check if you wish continue.

Comment: I was too strict.. i dont have experience with ActiveX or Java.. But like DaveRandom said it is sure possible with these technologies also (they work at the client)